# How can I install caffe on anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, caffe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPjoY.png)
I created an environment for caffe by `conda create -n caffe python=3.7` and then

Comment: There do not seem to be windows builds for `caffe` in well known conda repositories.

Comment: Check out the Windows branch https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows and this too https://github.com/happynear/caffe-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following if you are using the Linux system. I guess there are no window builds for caffee. You can check here [link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/caffe)

```
conda install -c anaconda caffe
```

It should work fine.